# How do I get EthAdapter?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I followed the docs of Protocol Kit. I want to connect to a Safe Wallet if it already exists or create a new one. My code : (assume things are defined above)

```
     signer = provider.getSigner();
     ethAdapterOwner1 = new EthersAdapter({
       ethers,
       signerOrProvider: signer
     })
    
    safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner1 })

    const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
      owners:[
        await signer.getAddress()
      ],
      threshold:1
    };

     // if safe exists then get it's address and connect to it
     let retrievedSafeAddress = localStorage.getItem("safeAddress");
     if(retrievedSafeAddress){
       const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapterOwner1, retrievedSafeAddress })
       return safeSdk;
     }

    const safeSdkOwner1 = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig })

    const safeAddress = await safeSdkOwner1.getAddress()
```

I am getting the following error : "Argument of type '{ ethAdapterOwner1: EthersAdapter; retrievedSafeAddress: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SafeConfig'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ethAdapterOwner1' does not exist in type 'SafeConfig'."

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapterOwner1, retrievedSafeAddress })
```

is not correct, it should be:

```
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({
  ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner1,
  safeAddress: retrievedSafeAddress
})
```

or like this is you rename the variables:

```
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress })
```

Answer (score -1):

To obtain an EthAdapter, you can access the appropriate contract or application on the Ethereum blockchain to connect and interact with Ethereum and other blockchains.